# How to deserialize json data in windows phone?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone

Initially my json was in the format,

```
"code": 0,
"message": "success",
"students": [
    {
        "id": "257633000000070001",
        "name": "hjeke",
        "percentage": 36,
        "type": "Good",
    },
    {
        "id": "257633000000073001",
        "name": "Second",
        "percentage": 4,
        "type": "bad",
    }]
```

And so i used the following class for deserializing using Newtonsoft.json

```
[DataContract]
public class students
{
    [DataMember(Name = "code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "students")]
    public StudentDetail StudentDetail { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class StudentDetail 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "percentage")]
    public double PercentageForEdit { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

But now my json is changed to,

```
"code": 0,
"message": "success",
"students": {
    "details":{
        "hjeke": {
            "id": "257633000000070001",
            "name": "hjeke",
            "percentage": 36,
            "type": "Good",
        },
        "Second": {
            "id": "257633000000073001",
            "name": "Second",
            "percentage": 4,
            "type": "bad",
        }
      }
  }
```

How should i change my **students** class so that,

```
  StudentDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Students>(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using Newtonsoft.Json, try to use that classes:

```
public class StudentDetails
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int percentage { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<StudentDetails> students { get; set; }
}
```

After that, you can use that class to Deserialize responses using following way:

```
var parsedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(data);
```

P.S. Of course, do not forget about `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes

Comment: I've just tested that solution and it works fine even without DataContract Attributes.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your Json does not seem to be valid, the surrounding brackets are missing for the object { }.
To find your matching C# class there is a nice converter [on this site](http://json2csharp.com/)

For your second Json with the object brackets:

```
"code": 0,
"message": "success",
"students": {
"details":{
    "hjeke": {
        "id": "257633000000070001",
        "name": "hjeke",
        "percentage": 36,
        "type": "Good",
    },
    "Second": {
        "id": "257633000000073001",
        "name": "Second",
        "percentage": 4,
        "type": "bad",
    }
  }
}
```

it suggests these classes:

```
public class Hjeke
{
  public string id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public int percentage { get; set; }
  public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Second
{
  public string id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public int percentage { get; set; }
  public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Details
{
  public Hjeke hjeke { get; set; }
  public Second Second { get; set; }
}

public class Students
{
  public Details details { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
  public int code { get; set; }
  public string message { get; set; }
  public Students students { get; set; }
}
```

You can play around with this generator tool by yourself.

Comment: FYI like hjeke and Second there are around 100 objects in _Details_ class.